# Computing limits

Tags: calculus, limits, circles

A circle of radius $1$ is centred at $(1, 0)$.  A chord of length $h$, $0 < h < 2$, intersects the circle at $(0, 0)$ and at the point $B$.  The point $A$ has coordinates $(0, h)$.  The line through $A$ and $B$ intersects the $x$-axis at a point with $x$-coordinate $P$.  Compute:  $ \lim_{h\to 0} P.$

[image]

So I'm torn on as $h$ approaches $0$, that the $P$ will go to $0$ or to $\infty$? I don't just want an answer but I want to gain the tools as to how to solve this problem. My calc teacher hasn's offered us the best tool to succeed. I'm willing to put in the work but don't know how to go about solving the issue.

Any help would be great.

Comment: And your thoughts are?

Comment: Please, use TeX for arranging formulas, and also it's better to paste the image to the post, not just provide a link. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using StackExchange as a poster. I really want to understand how to do this. But tutors at my school were unable to help. This is my las resort. I think the limit as h ->0 of P will be infinity or 0 but I don't know how to do this mathematically. I think that the circle equation is $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$ and if h=2 then P will cross the x-axis  at 2 (45,45 degree right triangle)

Comment: @user443101, not to worry.  If you look at "source" on my edit in the edit history (click on the "edited just now" above my name), you'll see how dollar signs make things look nice.  I would recommend you do an edit on your "I'm torn" paragraph to make it look nice too, for a bit of practice.

Comment: Note, by the nature of the construction, $P$ is always greater than $2$, so it can't go to $0$ as $h$ goes to $0$.

Comment: @BarryCipra, Good point! so it must go to $infinity$ then, I would assume.

Comment: You are on your way to learning TeX!  Next lesson:  "\infty" will produce $\infty$ when put inside dollar signs.

Comment: Question: if $h = {\sqrt 2} $ then P would be tangent to the circle at $x=1$, correct?

Comment: For what it's worth, this problem strikes me as one that is easily solved with the right clever idea, but can be a bit of a slog otherwise.  So far I haven't had any clever ideas.

Comment: @BarryCipra You're the man so far though! I appreciate you helping me enter the StackExchange world so far. I owe ya one.

Comment: first things first.  Find a formula for P(h) = .... in terms of h.  Simple trig should do it. ... I think.... it's too hot and I'm too lazy to work it out but $h = 2 \sin \angle P0B/2$ and from that we can get $\angle 0AP $ and the slope of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a brute force approach.

The equation for the circle is $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$, so an equation for top half of the circle is $y=\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}$, which simplifies to $y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}$.  If the coordinates of $B$ are $(x,y)=(x,\sqrt{2x-x^2})$, then $h^2=x^2+y^2=x^2+(2x-x^2)=2x$, so $h=\sqrt{2x}$, which means the coordinates of $A$ are $(0,\sqrt{2x})$.  The slope of the line connecting $A$ and $B$ is thus

$${\sqrt{2x-x^2}-\sqrt{2x}\over x-0}$$

But the slope of the line connecting $A$ and $P$ is

$$0-\sqrt{2x}\over P-0$$

Since it's the *same* line, we can equate these and solve for $P$:

$${\sqrt{2x-x^2}-\sqrt{2x}\over x}={-\sqrt{2x}\over P}\implies P={x\sqrt{2x}\over\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{2x-x^2}}$$

This now simplifies to

$$P={x\sqrt{2x}(\sqrt{2x}+\sqrt{2x-x^2})\over2x-(2x-x^2)}={2x^2+x\sqrt{4x^2-2x^3}\over x^2}=2+\sqrt{4-2x}$$

If you like, you can write this as $P=2+\sqrt{4-h^2}$.  The limit is now obvious:  as $h\to0$, $P\to2+\sqrt4=4$.

The relatively simple result suggests there ought to be a simpler way to obtain it, and this may be what the extra credit is hinting at, but I personally don't see it.  I hope someone else will.

Comment: Well, one of us made a mistake.  I'm going to assume it was me.

Comment: @fleablood I also arrived at 4 by a different method

Comment: Yeah, I'm wrong.  I may be playing fast and loose with limits or screwing up my derivatives.  Barry's is far more straightforward than mine but mine was how it occurs to me to solve $P$ in terms of $h$.

Comment: @fleablood, and Doug's approach is clearly the "right" way to do it!!!

Comment: Except doug did the math right and I didn't.

Comment: @fleablood, it was pure luck I got the right answer on the first attempt.  Normally it takes me three tries to do anything involving algebra correctly.

Comment: Oog.  If I used trig, I should have ... used trig.  Trying to use trig to get the equation of a line and to convert back... Oy.

Comment: Actually I meant (90 - t) - 90 as it ihas a negative slope.    That wouldn't have resulted in an error (factor of 2) I think.

Comment: @fleablood, OK, I wasn't sure if that was the fatal error.  Let's delete this interchange.

Answer (score 1):

If $\theta$ is the angle between the line from the origin to $B$ and the $y$ axis.

$h = 2\sin \theta$

The angle at $P = \frac {\theta}{2}$

$P = h\cot (\frac {\theta}{2}) = 2\sin\theta \cot (\frac {\theta}{2}) = 4\cos^2 \frac {\theta}{2}$

$\lim_\limits{h\to 0} P = \lim_\limits{\theta \to 0} 4\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}$